# Call a function with a dict as parameter

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am currently working on a command line interface with `argparse`. I receive the parsed arguments as a `Namespace` object from `arg_parse`. Basically the arguments coming in form the CLI should be passed down to 2 functions. Now I am looking for a smart way to split the `Namespace` such that I can simply use unpacking.

The following example should illustrate what I would need:

```py
import argparse
ns1 = argparse.Namespace(foo=1)
ns2 = argparse.Namespace(bar=2)
ns3 = argparse.Namespace(foo=1, bar=2)

def f(foo): return foo
def g(bar): return 10 * bar

f(**vars(ns1)) # works
g(**vars(ns2)) # works
f(**vars(ns3)) # does not work, 'bar' is not an argument of f
```

I could hard code the filter like in

```py
f_args = ["foo"]
g_args = ["bar"]

f(**{k:v for k, v in vars(ns3).items() if k in f_args}) # works
g(**{k:v for k, v in vars(ns3).items() if k in g_args}) # works
```

But this feels error prone (if the signature of `f` will change, I have to remember to change `f_args` as well.). I could however use `inspect.getfullargspec` to automatize this part like in:

```py
import inspect
f_args = inspect.getfullargspec(f).args
```

But this all feels hackish to me and I was wondering whether I am not overlooking an easy pattern for this?

---

**Update**

As pointed out by @doer_uvc one approach would be to treat my functions with a *"catch all"* parameter like in:

```py
def f(foo, **kwargs): return foo
```

While this is a viable solution, I would be curious to find solutions where I do not need to touch the signature of `f` itself.

Comment: It seems that this is unrelated to ``argparse`` and its ``Namespace``. You basically want to unpack *some* mapping to *some* function, skipping keywords the function does not accept?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes. The `Namespace` is indeed irrelevant to the problem at hand, but I thought that giving some context may help in case that there is a solution which goes in a completely different direction (to foster outside the box thinking, so to speak :))

Comment: I agree with @MisterMiyagi and would suggest updating the question title.

Comment: The question reads as 'Call a function with a dict as parameter' so no reference to `argparse` or `Namespace` the  tag to which you added by the way. So what would you suggest as a better title?

Comment: `Call a function that ignores arguments not specified in function signature `

Comment: @thothal.. Agree I should not have added those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If writing functions are within your scope then make your functions accept any number of keyword arguments and check for arguments of interest within function.

```
class MissingArgumentError(ValueError):
    pass


def f(**kwargs):
    if not 'foo' in kwargs:
        raise MissingArgumentError('Missing keyword argument `foo`')
    return kwargs['foo']


def g(**kwargs):
    if not 'bar' in kwargs:
       raise MissingArgumentError('Missing keyword argument `bar`')
    return 10 * kwargs['bar']
```

In this method, even if your function signature changes, nothing else needs to be changed.

---

If you have to write multiple such functions then rather than repeating logic of argument checking, you can use `decorators`.

```
def argverifier(compulsory_args:list):
    def actual_decorator(function):
        def inner(**kwargs):
            for arg in compulsory_args:
                if arg not in kwargs:
                    raise MissingArgumentError(f'Missing keyword argument : {arg}')
            return function(**kwargs)
        return inner
    return actual_decorator

@argverifier(compulsory_args=['foo'])
def f(**kwargs): return kwargs['foo']

@argverifier(compulsory_args=['bar'])
def g(**kwargs): return 10 * kwargs['bar']
```

---

If you do not wish to change signature of a function then the viable solution is to write a function that extracts arguments using `inspect` module as you suggested.

```
from functools import partial
import inspect

def f(foo): return foo
def g(bar): return 10 * bar

def argextractor(args, kwargs):
    return {k:v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in args}

f_argextractor = partial(argextractor, inspect.getfullargspec(f).args) 
g_argextractor = partial(argextractor, inspect.getfullargspec(g).args)

f(**f_argextractor(vars(ns3)))
g(**g_argextractor(vars(ns3)))
```

Comment: Nice +1. Like the part about writing own decorators. Though the functions are under my control, I would appreciate a solution where I do not need to use an extra `**kwarg` argument of my function, because this makes the signature of `f` (or `g`) unnecssarily hard to read. I know, I could simply add the `**kwatg` after the required args, but if there is a solution w/o a *"catch all"*  argument I would appreciate it. Will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @thothal, thanks.
I do not see any viable solution that does not involve using inspect , in that case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no shorthand for this. However, one can easily build this using `inspect.signature` – these are not hacks, Python signatures can get very complicated and `inspect` exists for just such purposes.

```
import inspect


def apply(call: 'Callable', kwargs: 'Dict[str, Any]'):
    """Apply all appropriate ``kwargs`` to ``call``"""
    call_kwargs = inspect.signature(call).parameters.keys()
    matching_kwargs = {name: kwargs[name] for name in kwargs.keys() & call_kwargs}
    return call(**matching_kwargs)
```

This inspects the parameters expected by `call`, and picks those supplied by `kwargs`. If `kwargs` is missing any parameters to `call`, the standard exception of missing parameters is thrown.

```
>>> def f(foo):
...     return foo
...
>>> apply(f, {'foo': 2, 'bar': 3})
2
>>> apply(f, {'baz': 2, 'bar': 3})
…
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks, so in principle this is equivalent to what I have, expect that you use `signature(call).parameters` instead of `getfullargspec`. Any advise to which one to prefer given that the do more or less the same?

Comment: Prefer using ``inspect.signature``. In recent Python versions, ``inspect.getfullargspec`` uses ``inspect.Signature`` behind the scenes and exists mostly for backwards compatibility with Python2. ["This function is retained primarily for use in code that needs to maintain compatibility with the Python 2 inspect module API."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi.. Cool :)
Your solution reminds me of Java's bifunction and functional interface.